# How to stop 405 error in Nuxt Supabase using Github auth on Vercel?

Tags: github, nuxtjs3, supabase

I have setup a simple crud application much like the Nuxt3 Supabase module demo (functionally identical).  I can run the app locally without any problems, when authorized,  the user is taken to the correct authenticated route and sees the demo. When I generate for production and deploy to vercel, with my environment variables entered and updating the url in both the Github OAuth and Supabase, I keep getting a 405 error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide any more details on the error? Screenshots, logs in vercel, the browser console etc.?